# Ubuntu 16.04 fsck returns error Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdc

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have a 1TB drive formatted as 4GB swap and the rest ext4 on `/`.  I have bad magic number in superblock and that superblock is corrupt according to `fsck`.  Running `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc` tells me 'Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdc' and asks proceed any way.  I have no idea how I have a dos partition as gparted only shows ext4 and swap I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: @Ravexina - thanks for the edit - sorry but I did not actually think I was writing code.  I thought I was just writing text to explain what I had done.  In hindsight I see 'askubuntu'  detects it as code - apologies again.  Could you remind me again how to format as code please.

Answer (score 2):

[Partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table) and partition's [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) are different and unrelated concepts.

`mke2fs` is reporting it found a 'msdos' or MBR partition table. Those can contain up to four primary partitions of any file system. Perhaps it expected GPT?

Comment: thanks but I am confused.  The partitions were created in Ubuntu - are you saying that the partition table was created with a different OS - and what is GPT

Comment: Both the old MBR and the new GPT can have partition of any file system. "msdos" is just a name. It doesn't mean the drive was initialized in other OS. GPT is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table and the new standard and mandatory for bigger drives, +3TB if I'm not mistaken. Any Windows 8 or newer requires GPT for UEFI mode installation (and MBR for legacy). Ubuntu and other modern distros are more flexible but following the same rule is usually recommended.